# What all options we have to deploy react app on Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure

What all options we have to deploy react web application to Azure?
Few options which I have already explored are: Azure web app, Container instance, Azure blob storage as static website.

What all other options we have to deploy the react web app to Azure? What option is better for react app (With regards to Availability, cost, maintenance)?

Also, To run react app, all we need is artifacts (like js, css, images etc.) which we can get by running simply build command so do we really need server to execute the code? can we not directly host it to some storage and then browsing it?

Comment: One newer option which you didn't mention is Azure Static Web App: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/static/#overview

Comment: App Service, Web App For Containers, Static Web Apps, Container Instances, Container Apps, Virtual Machines, Kubernetes Service, OpenShift, Service Fabric. Did I miss something?

Comment: @CSharpRocks Thanks for all these options. however VM, AKS, Service fabric are not meant for app like react. We know that all these computes are suitable for orchestration purpose. We need option for react app and why that option is suitable.